# Will _ would and Can_Could differences

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would, could-modal, can-modal

I read the below article in "The Hindu" newspaper:

> The state government has imposed restrictions on gatherings with immediate effect. Only 50 persons **would** be allowed at gatherings. The government ordered the closure of all the gymnasiums, spas, sports complexes and others with immediate effect. Funerals and related activities **could** be attended by not more than 20 persons.

My doubt here is, Shouldn't we use **will** and **can** instead of Would and Could??

What is the difference in meaning if we use will and can instead of would and could?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the restrictions are currently in force, because the present perfect "has imposed". Both can/will and could/would are valid, and each indicates a different perspective of the writer.

If you talk about a gathering that is planned to take place at 9am om the 11th of May, that is an actual gathering... God willing, it will happen at the specified time and date. If you talk about gatherings that have not yet been conceived of, let alone planned, they are hypothetical gatherings.

If you choose to talk about actual gatherings that will be affected, you use **will** and **can**, for example

> Only 50 persons **will** be allowed at gatherings.

If you choose to talk about the effect on hypothetical gatherings, you apply a backshift, using **would** and **could**. Some people refer to this as a [second conditional](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/second-conditional.html). here is an example:

> Only 50 persons **would** be allowed at gatherings.

Comment: Thankyou so much. But could you please explain what does “hypothetical gatherings” mean in your answer? What is the hypothesis there?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. If we think of “gatherings,” “funerals,” etc., as classes of events, then using *will* and *can* might feel more natural, and using *would* and *could* feels like we're talking about a hypothetical that has already come to pass.

However, if we think of these gatherings, funerals, etc. as hypothetical examples, then using *would* and *could* make some sense.

**Edit.** OP asked for clarification what "hypothetical" means here. A "hypothetical gathering" here means a gathering that does not exist, but is just supposed (as in "made up") to make a point. Since the gatherings being discussed don't actually exist, we use conditional words like *would* and *could*.

Comment: Thankyou so much. But could you please explain what does “hypothetical” mean in your answer? What is the hypothesis there?

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda I've added another paragraph to my answer to explain "hypothetical".